# a concept to check if at least one of the type in a list of types can be constructed from a given type

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I have a list of types `TypeList`. I am currently using a tuple to hold these types.
What I want is the following:

Given a new type `X` - check if at least one of the type from `TypeList` can be constructed from `X`. Also I want to use existing concept `std::constructible_from`

I started with the following concepts definitions:

```
template <typename From, typename To, std::size_t... Is>
concept ConstructibleFromHelper = requires(From from, To to) {
    requires (std::constructible_from<typename std::tuple_element<Is, To>::type,From> || ...);
};

template <typename From, typename To>
concept ConstructibleFrom = requires {
    requires ConstructibleFromHelper<From,To,std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<To>>()>;
};
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
./type_traits.h:36:46: error: template argument for non-type template parameter is treated as function type 'std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<To>> ()' (aka '__make_integer_seq<std::integer_sequence, unsigned long, std::tuple_size_v<To>> ()')
    requires ConstructibleFromHelper<From,To,std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<To>>()>;
```

Looks, like partial specialization of `ConstructibleFromHelper` is required to expand `make_index_sequence` to `std::size_t... Is`. But concept does not support partial specialisation.

How to make this work with `tuple` typelist and  `std::constructible_from`.
If this does not work, please suggest any other method to achieve the same result.

Thanks.

[failed attempt](https://godbolt.org/z/6hcrs8xv9)

Comment: Your helper might be a "simple" traits/regular template variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with an immediately-invoked lambda, i.e. by expanding the `tuple`'s elements directly in the function body

```
template <typename From, typename To>
concept ConstructibleFrom = []<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
  return (std::constructible_from<std::tuple_element_t<Is, To>, From> || ...);
}(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<To>>());
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jj1Gvq74c)

Comment: Thanks. So we are using class template to expand from `make_index_sequence`.
Using your example, I created another version here
https://godbolt.org/z/8YP5EWMc3